# Sticky Menu in JS

Tags: javascript, css, menu

everyone,

I've implemented a script that makes my menu sticky when scrolling down.

The function works, however it suddenly started behaving strangely when scrolling back up - instead of going back to its original position, it stays at the very top.

I must've changed something that caused this, but I can't figure it out.

The menu/script is on http://www.mtscollective.com.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
            if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() &gt; 175) {
                jQuery(&#39;.menu-secondary-wrap&#39;).css(&#39;position&#39;, &#39;fixed&#39;);
                jQuery(&#39;.menu-secondary-wrap&#39;).css(&#39;top&#39;, &#39;0&#39;);
                jQuery(&#39;.menu-secondary-wrap&#39;).css(&#39;width&#39;, &#39;950px&#39;);
                jQuery(&#39;.menu-secondary-wrap&#39;).css(&#39;box-shadow&#39;, &#39;0 -2px 6px 2px #555 &#39;);
    } else {
        jQuery(&#39;.menu-secondary-wrap &#39;).css(&#39; position &#39;,&#39; static &#39;);
    }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you separate the CSS and the javascript. You can then add/remove the specific CSS class using jQuery's `addClass`/`removeClass` methods. In addition to this I would store the distance from the menu to the document top into a variable using `$element.offset().top;`.

CSS

```
.static {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 950px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 6px 2px #555;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var $menu = $('.menu-secondary-wrap');
    var menu_top = $menu.offset().top;

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > menu_top ) {
            $menu.addClass('static');
        } else {
            $menu.removeClass('static');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrimsrud/Jhe3z/).
Hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you mean. Makes sense, however I've implemented your method and the menu is not fixed at all

Comment: I updated the JS in my answer. I then downloaded a local copy of your site and added the above JS to the very bottom of your site. It works as intended here. Do you still not see any improvement on your end?

Comment: I tried adding the updated script, but Blogger is very anal about XML. I'm getting the following error on the `\/` in the second line:
`Error parsing XML, line 4016, column 82: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.`

Comment: I got rid of the forward slash and it worked. However, it's referencing jQuery 1.9.1, which breaks my banner slider. I'm currently referencing 1.7.2.